# 8x8 LED Matrix has 26 pins

Tags: pinout, led-matrix

Recently I issued a 8x8 matrix from electronics club in my college (if thats what you want) without noticing the number of pins present on it.

Everywhere on the internet, working of 8x8 is explained as to light a LED we need to give positive and negative to row and column line in which LED is present. But here it doesn't seem to be applicable as there are 26 pins instead of 16. Same LED can made to glow with 3 different pairs of pin. Can anybody help me with whats going on or what are the possible pinouts? (HB19881ASR is written on it)

[image: photo of LED matrix showing part number HB19881ASR]

<sub>[Original photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qij5K.jpg)</sub>

Comment: You can use multimeters to analyse the pinouts. It is very difficult to speculate the pinout. You can check with your multimeter in continuity mode.

Comment: I tried its very confusing. It seems that there is no specific pattern. And the same led could be lighted with different pins don't know how.

Comment: Always buy components that come with a datasheet... “cheap” with no info can be more expensive...

Comment: As others have said, unfortunately you are seeing one reason why you need to check for the availability of datasheets *before* buying the components. :-( (a) Is there *any* part number or manufacturer name on the LED matrix? If so, please add that information to your question (a close-up, in-focus photo of the device showing those markings, *might* also help readers). (b) What did the shop where you bought the LED matrix say, when you asked them for its datasheet?

Comment: He said that there is no datasheet with it and he doesn't know how to operate it

Answer (score 2):

> Can anybody help me with whats going on or what are the possible pinouts?

If you have a problem with an IKEA furniture, you go back to IKEA. If you have problem with a game you contact the support of the developers who made the game.

If you buy something and you don't understand how it works, or need help with it. Then you go back to the "*nearby shop*". They are sitting on all the answers. If they don't know for some weird reason, then they can at least tell you where they got it from.

I recommend you to make a new rule in your life, from now on and forward, never buy electronics that doesn't have a datasheet.

Comment: Sorry Harry, this is 13 rambling paragraphs, only 1 of which is answering (and not that usefully). Downvoting.

Comment: @TonyM Less fuzz, more buzz?

Comment: Silliness removed so dv removed.

Comment: There is a reason I asked this question. I have tried everything I can think of and then I decided to ask.

Comment: @ApurvaNandan That's information that you've chosen to withheld from us, not my problem that you thought that it was not important. Which it clearly is. - On a more serious matter, why did your detective work end? Did the "*nearby shop*" not point you to their supplier?

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to determine the wiring of the matrix by 
measurement and observation.

Start by marking pin 1 clearly (eg use a marker pen or some tape)

Then measure which pins are connected directly to other pins

Finally pick one pin and see which leds can be lit using that pin and each of the other pins, use a low voltage 5V or less and a resistor. 
Repeat for each other pin.  record all observations.

EG: draw a grid and write which pins light each led in the corresponding grid cell.

Comment: Many/most LEDs have a very low reverse voltage max., something like 2 V. So this blind exploration method can destroy the LEDs under test when they're reverse-biased. Downvoting.

Comment: 5V is the lowest reverse limit I've ever seen for visible LEDs. Also  LEDs with a 2V reverse limit would be ill-suited to a matrix.

Comment: LED Vrrm are low voltages for diodes, where rectifier/signal are typically 20 V upwards. 2 V is common for discrete LEDs, just checked two 8x8 and both are 5 V. Your 5 V-and-resistor method damages both and you don't warn about Vrrm so I'm not sure what point you're making, I'm afraid.

Comment: if 5V is acceptable how does it damage both?  which LED has 2V max reverse?

Comment: I tried this but no two pins are directly connected 

Comment: There is a schematic tool in the editor buttons. Add a schematic of your test circuit so we know how you are testing.